# Is anyway of reducing the size of this Flutter app (120mb)

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSiJo.png)

Im having a problem with my flutter app it has three screens both with long text hard coded of 5000 lines and the other screen also has picture in scroll view

Comment: Can you post your code as text, not just an image? Images aren't very helpful for answering questions!

Answer (score 0):

The text shouldn't be much of a problem, but you should try to reduce the size of the image as much as possible or store it online and use [CachedNetworkImage](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image). I use gimp and [tinypng](https://tinypng.com/) to resize an image down and reduce its overall file size to what is really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Are you building in debug or release?
Please remember that debug builds are very large in size.
This link explains in details how your build behaves:

https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/app-size

If still after creating a release build the size is large, consider saving your large texts in a file in app directory on user device and reading it from there, you can use for example sembast database for local storage.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone,After appbundle the app size reduced from 120mb to 16mb